Как сделать двойной клик при одном нажатии js или jQuery
Суть проблемы в том что есть два сайта на вордпрес, и задача сделать синхронизацию пользователей и их данных на обеих сайтах.
Использую форму(анкету) профиля пользователя через плагин Profile Builder и плагин для синхронизации пользов. WordPress API Multiple Sites User Sync
и проблема в том что когда во фронтенде обновляешь профиль, то на другом сайте ничего нету, а когда жмешь два раза на кнопку тогда все данные переносятся на другой и все поля и данные тоже есть на другом сайте
вот прошу вас помочь сделать чтоб чел когда жмет на кнопку с определенымклассом или ИД автоматически нажималось два раза
или может есть у вас другое решение проблемы

Нужен код. Без кода: вызовите событие двойного клика dblclick. Эго так же можно эмулировать через new Event

Ошибка молотка (да нет, целого МОЛОТА) вынуждает придумывать КОСТЫЛИЩИ.. Синхронизацию нужно делать нормально. а это этим...
